# Chrome incognito windows always opens a second (unwanted) tab

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, private-browsing

every time I open a new Chrome incognito window, it always open a second incognito tab.
The url is:

```
http://norde.us/topelevenchromewebstore
```

that redirects to a facebook app link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=109306535771&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.5%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fapps.facebook.com%252Ftopeleven%252F%253Futm_source%253Dchromewebstore%2526utm_medium%253Dchromewebstore%2526utm_campaign%253Dchromewebstore%25252F%25253Faction%25253Dedit_display%2526keyword%253Dtopelevenchromewebstore%2526nonce%253Dee87392755%2526id%253Dy4289125807%26state%3Db18401bd0fb87a89f0ae04a0eb4bdcfc%26scope%3Dpublish_actions%252Cuser_friends%252Cemail%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D109306535771%26ret%3Dlogin%26sdk%3Dphp-sdk-5.6.1%26logger_id%3D61d122f9-a576-a18a-c4c4-4789dd81ac92&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Ftopeleven%2F%3Futm_source%3Dchromewebstore%26utm_medium%3Dchromewebstore%26utm_campaign%3Dchromewebstore%252F%253Faction%253Dedit_display%26keyword%3Dtopelevenchromewebstore%26nonce%3Dee87392755%26id%3Dy4289125807%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%3Db18401bd0fb87a89f0ae04a0eb4bdcfc%23_%3D_&display=page&locale=it_IT&logger_id=61d122f9-a576-a18a-c4c4-4789dd81ac92
```

This doesn't happen when the internet connection is disabled.
How do I solve it?

I already uninstalled the relative facebook app with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a rogue Chrome extension. Can you edit your question to list what extensions you have installed?

Comment: ^ That. Or do a hard-reset on Chrome and start again. chrome://settings/reset

Comment: I disabled all extension in incognito mode but keeps happening.

Comment: If I do an hard reset what will I lose? extensions as well?

Comment: If they are set to sync with a signed-in Google account, no.